# awk adding values to an existing column

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file that contains headers:

```
Name State PhoneNum Gender
```

The headers are tab separated

I have a array in shell `$GenderArray` that contains a few genders

I want to append the `$GenderArray` to the file such that:

```
Name State PhoneNum Gender
                    M
                    F
                    F
```

I am currently looping through the array as:

```
for i in ${GenderArray[@]};
do
    //APPENDED AWK CALL WOULD GO HERE?
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `print` with some tabs as padding:

```
{ cat file; printf "\t\t\t\t%s\n" "${GenderArray[@]}"; }

Name    State   PhoneNum        Gender
                                M
                                F
                                F
```

Answer (score 0):

You could print the content of `GenderArray` as a column,
and use `paste` to append it to a file:

```
printf "%s\n" "${GenderArray[@]}" | paste file.in - > file.out
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf "%s\n" "${GenderArray[@]}" |
awk 'NR==FNR{g[NR+1]="\t" $0; next} {print $0 g[FNR]}' - file
```

Untested of course since you didn't provide any sample input/output for us to test with.